# "Number is not compatible with column definition or is not available for a not nullable column"

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem when importing a txt file into an oracle table.

for some reason, SQL developer doesn't allow decimals to get imported as the image shows, and I believe that the data type is correct as it worked for me before.

please help, and thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: I think you might need a positive integer(presumably 6) for scale(echelle).

Answer (score 1):

Please check that the decimal seperator on your system has not changed since the last time this worked. To test this replace all dots(.) with commas(,) in the text file and check if the error goes away.

I have reproduced your error on my own system, where comma is the decimal seperator, and using a file that uses dot as the decimal seperator.

Not sure if the scale, -127, will cause any issues for you. NUMBER columns defined without precision and scale get the scale -127 in SQL Developer import engine. I have never noticed this before but it is present in version 20.2.0.175.